# Как исправить накладывание изображений в mansory.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Использую табы и mansory.js для изображений внутри. Если таб на момент загрузки не активен, то mansory накладывает изображения друг на друга. Но, при изменении размера окна все выравнивается.
Как исправить этот баг?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).foundation();
  Foundation.onImagesLoaded($('img'), function() {
    $('.grid').masonry({
      // options
      itemSelector: '.gallery-masonry__item',
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      gutter: 10,
      percentPosition: true,
      resize: true
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.gallery-masonry__item {
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /*   max-height: none; */
  /*   max-width: none; */
}

.grid-sizer {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.4-rc1/js/foundation.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.4-rc1/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x">
    <div class="medium-3 cell">
      <ul class="vertical tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
        <li class="tabs-title is-active">
          <a href="#panel1v" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-title">
          <a href="#panel6v">Tab 6</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-9 cell">
      <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
        <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1v">
          <p>One</p>
          <p>Check me out! I'm a super cool Tab panel with text content!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel6v">
          <p>Six</p>
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
            <div class="gallery-masonry__item">
              <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/220x150">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-masonry__item">
              <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/150x150">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-masonry__item">
              <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/220x300">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-masonry__item">
              <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/60x150">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-masonry__item">
              <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/225x150">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно проинициализировать masonry при изменении состояния таба:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).foundation();
  
  function grid(){
    Foundation.onImagesLoaded($('img'), function() {
      $('.grid').masonry({
        // options
        itemSelector: '.gallery-masonry__item',
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        gutter: 10,
        percentPosition: true,
        resize: true
      });
    });
  }
  
  grid();
  
  $('#example-tabs').on('change.zf.tabs', function() {
    grid();
  })
});
```

```css
.gallery-masonry__item {
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /*   max-height: none; */
  /*   max-width: none; */
}

.grid-sizer {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.4-rc1/js/foundation.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.4-rc1/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x">
    <div class="medium-3 cell">
      <ul class="vertical tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
        <li class="tabs-title is-active">
          <a href="#panel1v" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tabs-title">
          <a href="#panel6v">Tab 6</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-9 cell">
      <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
        <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1v">
          <p>One</p>
          <p>Check me out! I'm a super cool Tab panel with text content!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel6v">
          <p>Six</p>
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
            <div class="gallery-masonry__item">
              <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/220x150">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-masonry__item">
              <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/150x150">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-masonry__item">
              <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/220x300">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-masonry__item">
              <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/60x150">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-masonry__item">
              <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/225x150">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если есть несколько табов с masonry и несколько блоков табов, будет ли правильным такое решение, каждый раз при изменении табов инициализировать все блоки с mansory?

Comment: ну если не проинициализируете, то работать не будет, тк в закрытом табе masonry(либо любой другой скрипт который не расчитывает на это событие) их не увидит. Это обычная практика, события нет - т к самого элемента нет. А события стоят: загрузка и ресиз, например. Нужно прописывать. Подобное поведение будет при использовании модальных окон, слайдеров, выпадающих списков если не добавить обработчик. Обычное дело.